Client-side SQL in JS: Using the File System Access API
I'd like to create/use and store an SQLite (or any SQL) DB locally on the client, from the browser. This used to be impossible until approx late 2022 / early 2023, but now the File System Access API allows for direct file read/writes and is supported in most/all browsers.
(FYI my primary goals: my app works with data that users do not want transferred off their machine (for their own reasons), and it works with data that users want to manage backup/restore themselves - e.g. they're already storing similar data in their own SCM, and they want it together)
All I can find so far:

SQLite has a VFS backend that uses File System Access API - but only uses the cutdown "OPFS" sub-system. (I don't understand why they chose this - maybe OPFS gives better performance? - but it removes a lot of the core power of FSSA. e.g. OPFS does not store to hard-disk, it stores to a proprietary virtual location within the browser. OPFS by design prevents you from backup/restore/synch the database file. It also has a history of 'accidentally' deleting files occasionally - not common but reported by multiple people)
Using the File System Access API to wrap an SQLite DB - OK, works in theory, but used directly it only allows read-all/write-all semantics, so your SQL DB is going to be extremely slow (you're manually copying the whole thing to/from disk on every transaction?).
Using the API directly - write your own database library, reinventing the wheel, and spending years trying to implement a complete SQL.

Is there an option I'm missing, or something I've misunderstood? Is there another way to achieve this?

Are you missing this -> https://sqlite.org/wasm/doc/trunk/demo-123.md

@Keith from the top of that document: "Databases are transient - they disappear when the page is reloaded. Persisting them is possible but beyond the scope of this brief tutorial."

Yes, I know.  And then gives a link to -> https://sqlite.org/wasm/doc/trunk/persistence.md

... which only offers OPFS, as described in my question. (Technically also lists KVVFS but that is by-definition non persistent (it's 'temporarily persistent' and can be wiped at any moment by the browser) so maybe shouldn't be on that webpage)

I don't think FSSA has seek abilities does it, unless it's using OPFS.  Are you asking to be able to use FSSA file picker, and get direct access to this file rather than rely on OPFS?.  I'm not sure this is possible, but I might be wrong.

I believe tho whole idea of OPFS, is having the ability to read / write to a file that's sandboxed and not exposed to the underlining OS.  aka.  Not possible to store a virus locally.  This is not a problem for pure FSSA because it's prompted by design, IOW: each invocation requires user interaction, were as OPFS does not.  Could you not store locally and sync the DB's, similar to say Turso how it sync multiple instances of sqLite DB's.

Yep, that could be the blocker - i.e. due to browser-vendors security decisions there may be (still) no way to have a web-app write directly to a local DB stored on local hard-disk in a user-accessible location. I had thought (misunderstood?) that browser vendors had finally accepted this is a sensible and common use-case (it is!) and that so long as it's wrapped in reasonable forced prompts on users it should be supported. But maybe not.

Yeah, I agree.  I understand the reasons, but with proper obvious prompts & controls they should be no reason not to allow it.   I just wonder if it's deliberate, to force native apps, IOW: a conflict of interest, if the web could do everything a native app can do, then they would lose APP store fees.  A reason push notification on IOS took a stupid amount of time, and was only constant pressure that made it available.
